# How do I use AppGroups with multiple environments in an Xcode Project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I have an iOS app with a NotificationServices extension and CoreData.  I am using app groups (group.com.example.appName)

I have setup multiple configurations for my app so that I can have a dev and prod environment:

```
Debug Dev
Debug Prod
Release Dev
Release Prod
```

And I have modified my Scheme and in the target under build settings I have the following Product Bundle Identifiers in Packaging:

```
Debug Dev - com.example.appName.dev
Debug Prod - com.example.appName
Release Dev - com.example.appName.dev
Release Prod - com.example.appName
```

Everything works fine and I am able to build two versions of the app.  The problem is that I am using app Groups for my NotificationExtension and also because I like CoreData to be accessible in the extension I am initializing my CoreData stack with:

```
let groupName = "group.com.example.appName"
let databaseIdentifier = "appName.sqlite"
let url = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: groupName)!.appendingPathComponent(databaseIdentifier)
```

How would I be able to change the group name for the dev environment so that the same database is not shared with the two apps?

Do I need to create another group called group.com.example.appName.dev?  And if so how do I specify that the dev environment uses this group?

Answer (score 0):

you can try it:

```
if let appDomain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
       let databaseIdentifier = "\(appDomain).sqlite"
       let url = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: appDomain).appendingPathComponent(databaseIdentifier)
        }
```

Comment: I need to use the app group container not the bundleIdentifier